# Console.log not showing on browser when called from src file

Tags: javascript, html

Feel like this is a really stupid question but i cant find info anywhere on it and im 99% sure it worked before?

When i call console.log from a src file i dont see it on the console but i do when i call it from the script in the index.html it works fine?

i've tried on chrome/firefox and safari and they all behave the same so i assume there is a reason for it. has anyone any documentation or knowledge on it?

thanks in advance!

source file index.js:

```
console.log('hi there');
```

index.html

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1\> Hello world</h1>
        <script>
            src = 'index.js'
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<script>src = 'index.js'</script>` -> `<script src = 'index.js'></script>`

Comment: This is not how you define a script when using src. Use `src` as an attribute `<script src="index.js" />`

Comment: Thanks folks, I did say I thought it was a stupid question! Can’t believe I missed that one! Syntax as always!

Comment: Additionally, that backslash in `<h1\>` doesn't look right, and you'll need a `<` in front of `!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, your syntax is not ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> Hello world</h1>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Btw. before javascript, try to look on HTML.